# Enabling Policies on Chrome for Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac

With the update of Chrome v58, a lot of our internal sites are now appearing as insecure due to the local certs and self signed certs we're using.  I put the workaround in for our Windows machines using GPO and enabling the key EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors in the registry.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to enable a local policy for Chrome on a Mac. I found the file that I believe I need to edit called /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest/Contents/Resources/com.google.chrome.manifest.  In that file I found the policy I just can't figure out how to turn it on.

Once I figure it out I can push out the change to my company with our Mac management software (Jamf)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just type this into a Terminal

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors -bool true
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've tried editing so many random files and couldn't find the magic incantation here. Super helpful!

Comment: What's the `-bool true` for

Comment: it means set the value to true. not String type "true" but boolean type true

Comment: I had to restart Chrome to make this take effect `defaults write com.google.Chrome HSTSPolicyBypassList -string "localhost"`

Answer (score 2):

I *think* we figured it out.

We needed to create a file called "com.google.Chrome.plist" in /Library/Managed Preferences

That file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple/DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This worked and we pushed it out using Jamf. That said, if someone has a better way to do this please let me know.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Are you sure it's `Managed Preferences` and not `Preferences`?