# Chrome browser's single tab is consuming 750 MB of RAM. How can I reduce this utilization?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, memory, browser, utilization

When I open my webpage in a Chrome tab, it uses around 750 MB of RAM. (I have check the usage in Chrome's task manager.) I am using Windows 7.

When I open the same webpage in 8 tabs, then the total RAM usage of my system is 6.27 GB.

I have checked the RAM usage of other webpages such as youtube.com, but it uses 180 MB of RAM (average). Can any one tell me how I can reduce this RAM usage. Is there any way to find out problems by using Chrome profiling?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limiting use of RAM in Chrome?](http://superuser.com/q/413349/10259) and/or [Why do web pages take so much RAM?](http://superuser.com/q/368263/10259)

Comment: capture trace of the memory usage grow of Chrome with xperf: http://pastebin.com/gR0eGqrX compress the file and share the compressed file

Comment: not a duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/413349/10259 because that question asks how to set a limit on RAM usage and this question asks how to reduce the actual problem, not just set a limit

Comment: What extensions do you have installed? What happens if you disable a few or all of them?